# Почему у меня вместо фамилии записывается пол при добавление записей в словарь

Tags: python-3.x

Доброго времени суток, друзья! Скажите, пожалуйста, что я делаю не так? Почему у меня вместо фамилии записывается пол?

```
Tourists={'surname':{},'age':{},'sex':{},'eyecolor':{}}
n=int(input('Введите количество добавляемых объектов '))
for i in range(0,n,1):
Tourists['surname'[i]]=input('Введите фамилию ')
Tourists['age'[i]]=input('Введите возраст ')
Tourists['sex'[i]]=input('Введите пол ')
p=int(input ('Выберите цвет глаз: 1)Зеленые, 2)Карие, 3)Голубые, 4)Серые, 5)Желтые, 6)Черные '))
if p==1:
    Tourists['eyecolor'[i]]='Зеленые'
elif p==2:
    Tourists['eyecolor'[i]]='Карие'
elif p==3:
    Tourists['eyecolor'[i]]='Голубые'
elif p==4:
    Tourists['eyecolor'[i]]='Серые'
elif p==5:
    Tourists['eyecolor'[i]]='Желтые'
else:
    Tourists['eyecolor'[i]]='Черные'
print (Tourists['surname'[i]])
print (Tourists['age'[i]])
print (Tourists['sex'[i]])
print (Tourists['eyecolor'[i]])
```

Вот что выводит:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вы наверное это имели ввиду: `Tourists['eyecolor'][i]='Зеленые'` это касается и всех остальных обращений к `Tourists`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Потому, что

```
'surname'[i]
```

при i = 0 - это 's'

И выводите Вы соответственно:
`Tourists['s'],Tourists['a'],Tourists['s'],Tourists['e']`

Comment: Да это касается и всего остального :)